# My button not appears to correct position when viewController is refreshed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, programmatically-created

I am creating a simple UIButton programmatically with this frame size

```
UIButton *pickmeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 100, self.view.bounds.size.width, 60)];
```

it display at perfect place where i want

[image]

But on some action i want to reload the whole view controller, when i do it display the button at wrong coordinates

[image]

First, i am unable to find the reason for it. Second, what i think according to coordinates i have defined i think the second image is rendering the correct coordinates because, placement on Y coord is (self.view.bounds.size.height - 100) and height is 60. But when i make it -60 it starts displaying button below bottom line and very little of button shows up above.

Kindly share your views and solution on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set AutoresizingMask for button

```
 UIButton *pickmeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 60, self.view.bounds.size.width, 60)];
 [pickmeButton setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this.

```
UIButton *pickmeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 60, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 60)];
```